# With Angular routing, why doesn't the template of a routing module wrap the content of router-outlet?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxshab

When `Appsite` is loaded as a component, https://angular-vxshab.stackblitz.io/app-component/sample it works how I would consider correctly, with output like,

```
[begin] app-component
[begin] appsite-component
[begin] sidenav

sample works!
[end] sidenav
[end] appsite-component
[end] app-component
```

Snippet of that route load from `app-routing.module.ts`,

```js
  {
    path: 'app-component',
    component: AppsiteComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'sample',
        loadChildren: () => import('./sample/sample.module')
          .then(mod => mod.SampleModule)
      }
    ]
  }
```

I would like it to be lazy loaded, and all the routing self-contained in `appsite-routing.module.ts` like,

```js
  {
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: () => import('./appsite/appsite.module')
      .then(mod => mod.AppsiteModule)
  }
```

But the outcome from that https://angular-vxshab.stackblitz.io/app/sample , I get what I would consider the *incorrect* output,

```
[begin] app-component
sample works!

[end] app-component
```

Where neither appsite-component, nor sidenav is "wrapping" the `sample-component`'s content (it's acting just like `rawsite-routing.module.ts` is designed to).

The funny thing is, I'm *sure* I've done this previously, by accident, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out now.

*app-component.html*

```html
<div>[begin] app-component</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div>[end] app-component</div>
```

*app-appsite.html*

```html
<div>[begin] app-appsite</div>
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
<div>[end] app-appsite</div>
```

*sidenav-component.html*

```html
<div>[begin] sidenav</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div>[end] sidenav</div>
```

*sample.html*

```html
<p>sample works!</p>
```

Comment: What is a 'template of a routing module'.

A `routing.module.ts` file will not have a template, correct? What dark wizardry is this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what to call it (which means I can't google it :/ ).  Basically something that's like the entry-point, app-component.  It's both a component, and a routing module. It's template is rendered around the output from router-outlet in its html.

Comment: I've heard the entry-point/top-level parent component referred to as the 'application shell'.

Not sure if this helps, but recall that all the <router-outlet> does is act as a buoy for where to dump a routed component's template (immediately *after* the <router-outlet> tag). https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet